# Flutter - firebase_auth updateProfile method is not working

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

I'm creating app using Flutter with Firebase. I have some weird issues. I'm creating authentication and it is working fine but when i try to add some collections to my Firestore Database, the record of displayName is set to null.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> createUser(email, password, displayName) async {
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);

    UserUpdateInfo info = new UserUpdateInfo();
    info.displayName = displayName;
    _auth.updateProfile(info);

    Firestore.instance.collection('users').document().setData({
      'name': user.displayName,
      'uid': user.uid,
      'email': user.email,
      'isEmailVerified': user.isEmailVerified,
      'photoUrl': user.photoUrl,
    });

    return user;
  }
```

this is Future class that creates user.

```
void _handleSubmitted() {
    userAuth
        .createUser(
        emailController.text, passwordController.text, nameController.text)
        .then((onValue) {
      print("Sign Up button clicked: $onValue");

    });
  }
```

this method is handle when sign up button is clicked.

and collection looks like this picture.

[image: collection]

Comment: Check if displayName has a value before you upload it. Sometimes Google users did not set up a name. Same with photoUrl.

Answer (score 19):

If I recall correctly, the local user profile is not immediately updated when you call `updateDisplayName` or `updatePhotoURL`. This means you should either just write the local values to the database (easiest) or force a reload of the profile (safest).

#### Write the local values

As said, this is the simplest approach:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc().set({
  'name': displayName,
  'uid': user.uid,
  'email': user.email,
  'isEmailVerified': user.emailVerified, // will also be false
  'photoUrl': user.photoURL, // will always be null
});
```

Note that `emailVerified` will always be false, and `photoUrl` will always be `null` on a newly created email+password account.

#### Force a reload of the profile

You can force a reload of the user data by calling [FirebaseUser.reload()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseUser.html#reload()):

```
await _auth.currentUser!.updateDisplayName(displayName);
await _auth.currentUser!.updateEmail(newEmail);
await _auth.currentUser!.updatePhotoURL(photoURL);
await _auth.currentUser!.reload();

user = _auth.currentUser;
```

Comment: I think using the Local Veriable is perfect for choice for updatation....

Answer (score 5):

To Update users display name and photo url this will definitely helpful.

```
  FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();

  UserUpdateInfo userUpdateInfo = new UserUpdateInfo();
  userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
  userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = url;

  user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
```

Answer (score 5):

It's inconvenient the way Firebase Auth works, and they say it won't change for now, so I made a package to address this, grab it here: [firebase_user_stream](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_user_stream)

In the Readme I explain the issues and how the package fixes them, there are examples and etc, enjoy!

EDIT (Jul/2020):

Firebase Auth for Flutter now has a `userChanges` stream:

> which triggers whenever auth state, id token or profile changes occur. Essentially, this acts as a way to obtain realtime changes on currently stateless functionality (such as updateProfile).

Comment: I appreciate you posting this, but I searched and cant seem to find `userChanges` steam referenced anywhere in the docs. How do I locate where userChanges stream is found?

Comment: I think it's not published yet on the stable branch, it's a feature still in beta. Once it's stable I will add a note in my package about this.

Comment: Thanks @michel-feinstein, you rock.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried everything but however, this works for me! Just call the FirebaseAuth.instance twice like the one in the code.

```js
      FirebaseUser currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();
      await currentUser.reload();
      currentUser = await _auth.currentUser();

      print("Current User   ${currentUser.displayName}");
      print("Current User   ${currentUser.photoUrl}");
```

hope this helps you!