# Unable to set FirebaseUser photoUrl to null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

**What I'm trying to do**

I'm trying to delete user image (by setting photoUrl = null).
Here is my code:

```dart
    final UserUpdateInfo updatedInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    updatedInfo.photoUrl = null;
    print(updatedInfo.photoUrl);
    final user = await _auth.currentUser();
    print('Before update: ${user.photoUrl}');
    await user.updateProfile(updatedInfo);
    await user.reload();
    final newUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
    print('After update: ${newUser.photoUrl}');
```

**Expected Output:**
The expected out is to get null from `newUser.photoUrl`.

**Actual Output**

```dart
I/flutter (10813): null
I/flutter (10813): Before update: test20, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/****/o/profileImages%2FIMG_20200129_133820.jpg?alt=media&token=6597dd66-e3b3-4b87-84b4-9000ceea54b4
I/flutter (10813): After update: test20, https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/****/o/profileImages%2FIMG_20200129_133820.jpg?alt=media&token=6597dd66-e3b3-4b87-84b4-9000ceea54b4
```

Don't know what is the actual issue. The same code works if I'm updating the photoUrl with a new url but doesn't work while setting it to null.

Comment: What is `UserUpdateInfo` class? This does not look like standard Firebase api.

Comment: I'm using flutter, and this is the class provide under ```package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart```

Comment: Maybe this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50990615/2000603

Comment: Already gone through it and have already implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.

You have to set:

```json
{ photoURL: '' }
```

instead of `null`. I think it is a bug.

J